# in django how to output table data to html template?

Tags: html, django, templates, view

I have created model, write views, and urls and html template file but can't show data when doing. If you know the reason please help me?
this is 3 file in django project
**models.py**

```
# from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db import models
# from rest_framework.authtoken.admin import User
from schedule import settings

class GiaoVien(models.Model):
    madotxep = models.ForeignKey(DotXep, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    hodem = models.CharField(default='', max_length=50)
    ten = models.CharField(default='', max_length=20)
    viettat = models.CharField(default='', max_length=20)
    nhomgv = models.CharField(default='', max_length=20)
    mamau = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    stt = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    ghichu = models.TextField(default='')

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id)
```

**views.py**

```
enter code here
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from inputdata.models import GiaoVien
def show(request):
    queryset = GiaoVien.objects.all()
    context= {'clientes': queryset}
    return render(request, "Main/showdata.html", context)
```

**showdata.html**

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block title %}Show Giao Vien{% endblock %}

{% block content %}

<table>
    <thead>
    {% for field in clientes %}
        <th>{{ field.label }}</th>
    {% endfor %}
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        {% for field in clientes %}
            <td>{{ field.value|default_if_none:'' }}</td>
        {% endfor %}
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
{% endblock content %}
```

Comment: Answers below for pure Django. You could also look at the Django-tables2 package https://django-tables2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pages/tutorial.html

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that you don't have a "label" field or a "value" field on your model. So you are not printing anything because this fields don't exist. Try something like this:

```
    {% for field in clientes %}
        <td>{{ field.madotxep |default_if_none:'' }}</td>
        <td>{{ field.hodem |default_if_none:'' }}</td>
        <td>{{ field.ten |default_if_none:'' }}</td>
        <td>{{ field.viettat |default_if_none:'' }}</td>
    {% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

django template itself don't render the table for you with label or value, you need to specify the table header and it's contents in the loop yourself:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <th>id</th>
        <th>madotxep</th>
        <th>hodem</th>
        <th>ten</th>
        <th>viettat</th>
        <th>nhomgv</th>
        <th>mamau</th>
        <th>stt</th>
        <th>ghichu</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        {% for client in clientes %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{ client.id|default_if_none:'' }}</td>
            <td>{{ client.madotxep|default_if_none:'' }}</td>
            <td>{{ client.hodem|default_if_none:'' }}</td>
            <td>{{ client.ten|default_if_none:'' }}</td>
            <td>{{ client.viettat|default_if_none:'' }}</td>
            <td>{{ client.nhomgv|default_if_none:'' }}</td>
            <td>{{ client.mamau|default_if_none:'' }}</td>
            <td>{{ client.stt|default_if_none:'' }}</td>
            <td>{{ client.ghichu|default_if_none:'' }}</td>
         </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
</table>
```